# Time-based expiration After 30 minutes of inactivity and At midnight

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

I created a cookie function to set 30-minute cookies. And it's working.

I want to alter the code and want to handle a single case. The cookie should expire automatically at midnight (or 12 a.m.). ***(i.e., if the cookie is set at 11:45, it should expire at midnight and after 12 a.m. new cookie should be set)***

So it should work fine in both cases with a 30-minute cookie and a midnight expiration.

***Code Example:***

**

```
function set30MinuteCookie(cname, cvalue) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000);
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires;
}
set30MinuteCookie();
```

**

Comment: Have you tried anything to achive this so far? Why did it not work?

Comment: @VincentMenzel I tried couple of approaches. 30-minute cookies scenario is working fine now want to implement at midnight expiration.